# Load CSS and JS efficiently in Rails ("Use a CDN for all static assets")

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, google-webfonts

I ran an analysis on www.webpagetest.org and it told me this..

```
> Use a CDN for all static assets: 89/100
> 
> FAILED - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700
> FAILED - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script FAILED
> - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic
> FAILED -
> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700
> FAILED - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCDEFG=places
```

I load these CSS and JS scripts as follows:

## head partial in my layout file

```
<HEAD>
  ... code...
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCDEFG&libraries=places", :defer => "defer" %>
  ... code ...
</HEAD>
```

## application.scss in assets/stylesheets folder

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* Font-Awesome CDN */
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css');

/* Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700');
```

I am trying to optimize the loading of my page,

1) What does "Use a CDN for all static assets" mean? I thought these are coming from a CDN?

2) What is the best way to load this CSS and JS code efficiently.

3) Should download all these files instead of referencing the URL from my server?

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a CDN for all static asset means
basically to load your photos as well as bootstrap files or Google fonts....  you can use a CDN or Content Distribution Network

for example you can use an Amazon s3 bucket to save your photos that are on your website that way when a visitor requests your website it loads faster because there are 2 different servers providing the website. one provides the html whilst the CDN is responsible for the heavy images videos or large css/JS files .

2) the most efficient way I have loaded CSS and JS  files is asynchronous

3) not sure what you mean? but the correct way is to use webpacker on rails6  and above